# Where can I get material for learning Castle?

Tags: castle, dynamic-proxy

Where can I get material for learning Castle? And How To Use DynamicProxy for Castle?

Answer (score 0):

I found their documentation site to be helpful when I was learning about Castle:

http://docs.castleproject.org/default.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Also, if you have any questions in particular feel free to ask here and I'll do my best to help :)